# iOS: read sms while app is active, like Drivesafe.ly does

Tags: ios, sms

Can you point me to a method which allow an app read sms messages while the app is active.

I know many people say it's not possible, but Drivesafe.ly does it and I know some bank apps do that. The only condition for that to work is that the app is currently active (shown on the screen).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iam afraid its still not possible on iPhone. If you check the [iTunes page](https://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/drivesafe-ly/id412490747?mt=8#038;ls=1) for Drivesafe.ly app, there is a notice about that.

It says:

> ...the application does not read native text messages out loud that come directly from your wireless carrier. Unfortunately, this is not technically possible on iOS devices today...